# Why am I getting an inconsistent path format with FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath method?

Tags: vb.net, string, path, string-concatenation, folderbrowserdialog

I keep getting an inconsistent path format with the FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath method, more specifically the path returned seems to be randomly missing or having the trailing backslash, this is causing problems for me for the following line of code

```
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(Filename:=dialog.SelectedPath & "Excel_Export_" & dt.ToString("ddMMMyyyy") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52)
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: @Plutonix, thanks for your comment, but I am afraid that the `Path.Combine` is not working, the constructed string returned is `Excel_Export_\18August2015\.xlsm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Path.Combine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you construct a valid, fully qualified filename.  Rather than trying to squeeze everything into a one liner:

```
Dim xFil As String = "Excel_Export_" & dt.ToString("ddMMMyyyy") & ".xlsm"
xFil = Path.Combine(dlg.SelectedPath, xFil)
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(Filename:= xFil, FileFormat:= 52)
```

If the files were going into folders bearing the date (which is what your code looked like at first glance), the date string would be one of the folder args:

```
Dim xFil As String = "Sales_" & dt.ToString("MMyyyy") & ".xlsm"
xFil = Path.Combine(dlg.SelectedPath, dt.ToString("ddMMMyyyy"), xFil)
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(Filename:= xFil, FileFormat:= 52)
```

The point is, `Path.Combine()` wont ever miss a directory separator or add an extra one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a backslash between the path and the filename:-

```
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(Filename:=dialog.SelectedPath & "Excel_Export_" & dt.ToString("ddMMMyyyy") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52)
```

It should be:-

```
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(Filename:=dialog.SelectedPath & "\" & "Excel_Export_" & dt.ToString("ddMMMyyyy") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52)
```

And my code would have been:-

```
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(dialog.SelectedPath + "Excel_Export_" + dt.ToString("ddMMMyyyy") + ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52)
```